# How to capture or log diagonal mousemovement?

Tags: javascript, events, cursor, mousemove, diagonal

I basically want to move the spider diagonally like an 8 way movement with mouse but I am not sure thats possible? My thoughts: If the x and y coordinates change at the same time then it is diagonal movement right? I can't find anything on diagonal mouse movement.

HTML

```
<html>

  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" 
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="spiderweb"><i id="cursor" class="fas fa-spider"></i></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  cursor: none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.spiderweb {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: aliceblue;
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/31/20/12/spider-web-1295590_1280.png);
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fa-spider {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

#cursor {
  position: absolute;
/*   transition-duration: 0.1s; */
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}
```

JS

```
//Get cursor element , set store x and y position//
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector("#cursor");
var oldx = 0;
var oldy = 0;
var direction = "";

//listen to cursor move and get page coordinates
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  var yPos = event.pageY;
  var xPos = event.pageX;
  //set cursor to match page coordinates
  mouseCursor.style.top = yPos + "px";
  mouseCursor.style.left = xPos + "px";
  //determine direction cursor is moving
  if (xPos > oldx) {
    direction = "right";
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
  } else if (xPos < oldx) {
    direction = "left";
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)";
  } else if (yPos > oldy) {
    direction = "down";
    oldy = yPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
  } else if (yPos < oldy) {
    direction = "up";
    oldy = yPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  }

  console.log(direction);
```

Link to my Code Pen Example
[SpiderCursor](https://codepen.io/lacheporter/pen/RwKmYJm?editors=1111)

Comment: I can provide an answer, but until I get to it, lookup 2D vector math for games. Very simple stuff despite how it may sound.

Answer (score 1):

To answer most simply, yes, if both x and y coordinates are changing, then you are moving in some sort of diagonal fashion, thus as you are NOT moving EXACTLY up and down or EXACTLY left and right. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: would this  seem like it works??   I don't know how to post a code block in comment)                                                                                                  
else if (xPos > oldx && yPos < oldy){
    direction = "upright";
    oldy = yPos;
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";

  }

Comment: Yes, looks good to me. I ran your code. It appears your upRight is firing correctly. Are you seeing an issue?

Comment: You have to think, when you are moving your mouse, you aren't always going to move in a perfect direction. Sometimes, you'll move in straight lines, but not always...

Comment: I was working on it while i waited for response and got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CHANGED CODE (might be a better way to shorten this?)

````
if (xPos > oldx && yPos < oldy) {
    direction = "upright";
    oldy = yPos;
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
  } else if (xPos < oldx && yPos < oldy) {
    direction = "upleft";
    oldy = yPos;
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(-45deg)";
  } else if (xPos > oldx && yPos > oldy) {
    direction = "downright";
    oldy = yPos;
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(135deg)";
  } else if (xPos < oldx && yPos > oldy) {
    direction = "downleft";
    oldy = yPos;
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(-135deg)";
  } else if (xPos > oldx) {
    direction = "right";
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
  } else if (xPos < oldx) {
    direction = "left";
    oldx = xPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)";
  } else if (yPos > oldy) {
    direction = "down";
    oldy = yPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
  } else if (yPos < oldy) {
    direction = "up";
    oldy = yPos;
    mouseCursor.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  }```
````